# Do I need a macro or can I do this with a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, macros

I am looking to refactor some code with a template. I know I can do it easily with a macro, but would prefer a template/inline lambda. It should be functionally equivalent.

The code is as follows:

```
static const Name AssetName = Name(TEXT("AssetName")); 
AssetPtr = (AssetPtrType*)GetAssetFromName(AssetName);

if (!AssetPtr)
    return false;
```

The static const etc. is very important, to optimize as this function can be called a thousand times, and there are lots of assets to load. So how can I generalize?:

```
#define LOAD_ASSET(AssetName, AssetPtr, AssetPtrType)

LOAD_ASSET(CoolTexture, this->CoolTexture, Image)
LOAD_ASSET(CoolModel, this->CoolModel, Mesh)
```

I can use any C++11/14/etc functions supported by the most up to date MSVC.

Comment: Please could you tell me the advantage of refactoring this code? PS: I think macros will be the wrong way to go

Comment: Just to clarify, will the variable `AssetName` actually have different names for all the different assets? Also, you say you will load thousands of assets, but will you do this during the runtime of the program, or only at the start? Will you ever reload an asset? Will you reuse the `AssetName` variable anywhere else outside of the loading? The `static const` part seems like premature optmization to me, have you benchmarked and measured that it is a major bottleneck?

Comment: Everything is contained to the scope of a class member function. I'm using an engine that needs to call it a lot though. This runs on the UI thread. We can assume AssetPtr, AssetName and "AssetName" are lexographically identical, and every asset will have a different name. AssetPtrType will be the templatized part I imagine, it can't be generalized.

Comment: The problem is that outside of preprocessor macros you can't get a string from a symbol, so if you want to use unique variable names then you must use macros. Otherwise it would be easy to create a simple function, especially if the assets are all part of a class inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: To me, your question is still unclear. Is it that, you want `LOAD_ASSET` to be replaced with something else (probably your 1st code snippet). And are you asking if to use macro or templates? How are you going to use this utility?

Comment: I want to have a thousand LOAD_ASSET() instead of a thousand copy/pastes of the 1st snippet. The part that has me stuck is the static variable with a string in it.

Comment: It will be good for others, if you put some minimal example to demonstrate, how do you intend to use this utility. Because any solution (be it macro-based or template-based) will rely on that context. As of now, it's still unclear. BTW, while replying to other user (non-owner of the post), like me or anyone, put "@" symbol before their username. e.g. @JoachimPileborg. This is the only way they can be notified that you have commented something. For example, because of "@" for "Jaochim", the user will be notified and will see that it was just an example taken. :-)

Comment: Why not initialise an array of strings? Then iterate through that list. So why are you using a cast and then subsequently throwing away the return value. I would imaging a class with a thousand different member variables is not the intention.

Comment: Are you using  the  variable AssetName anywhere else in the code?

Comment: What I find  surprising is that creating the name seems to be such an expensive operation that you want to optimize it with a static variable, but actually loading the asset is not.

Comment: What are `TEXT` and `Name`?

Comment: @leemes: `TEXT` is a macro that returns a wide- or narrow-width string depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined, and `Name` is probably a `typedef` that is set to `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the question of whether you should do this at all, I think the (almost) literal translation would be:

```
template<size_t CNT, class T>
void loadAsset(const char* AssetName, T*& AssetPtr) {
    static const Name an = Name(TEXT(AssetName));         
    AssetPtr = (T*)GetAssetFromName(an);
    if (!AssetPtr) {
        throw SomeSensibleException{}; 
    }
}    

int foo()
{
    try {
        loadAsset<0>("CoolTexture", this->CoolTexture);
        loadAsset<1>("CoolModel", this->CoolModel);        
    } catch (SomeSensibleException&) {
        return false
    }     
}
```

The problem is that you need a separate template function instantiation for each asset, not only for each asset type. Otherwise multiple assets should share the same static variable.   Now from the top of my head, I can't think of a - non-macro - way to use the string literal both, as a template and a function parameter, which is the reason for the additional counter.

If foo is inside a source file, you might be able to replace the manual counting with `__COUNTER__`, although I'm not sure if it has portable semantics. This would be dangerous if foo gets compiled ib multiple translation units as `__COUNTER__` could have different values and you would have a odr violation.

If you have actually verified, that using a local static variable brings a noticeable improvement in performance in you original code, I'd rather stick to the macro version and at least profile the template version before you use it.

Comment: You may clarify the need of `CNT`.  Not obvious it was to have the `static` name working.